# i want to transpose a dataframe having string

Tags: python, pandas

i want to transpose a dataframe having strings values

i have mentioned the code below

```
df_new= pd.pivot_table(df,values = 'col4', index = ['col1','col2'],
columns = ['col3'])
```

available output

```
col1    col2    col3    col4        
a   1   1   aa      
a   1   2   bb      
a   1   3   cc      
a   1   4   dd      
b   2   1   ee      
b   2   2   ff      
b   2   3   gg      
b   2   4   hh
```

desired output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzwhr.png)

Comment: show us your original dataframe

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) if unique combination `col1`, `col2` and `col3`:

```
df_new = (df.set_index(['col1','col2','col3'])['col4']
            .unstack()
            .add_prefix('col3_')
            .reset_index()
            .rename_axis(None,1))

print (df_new)
  col1  col2 col3_1 col3_2 col3_3 col3_4
0    a     1     aa     bb     cc     dd
1    b     2     ee     ff     gg     hh
```

And if possible duplicates then aggregate function `join`:

```
df_new= pd.pivot_table(df,values = 'col4', 
                       index = ['col1','col2'],
                       columns = ['col3'], 
                       aggfunc=','.join).add_prefix('col3_').reset_index().rename_axis(None,1)

print (df_new)
  col1  col2 col3_1 col3_2 col3_3 col3_4
0    a     1     aa     bb     cc     dd
1    b     2     ee     ff     gg     hh
```